Adding a data variable to Xarray dataset by iterating over existing variable
I would like to add a data variable to a xr.Dataset using another existing variable as the input for a function.
Ex, to create another variable by calling my_func for each Tair value in the dataset, I can do this, but is there a preferred way to do that?
ds = xr.tutorial.load_dataset("rasm")
ds['new_var'] = ( ('time', 'x', 'y'), np.array([ [ [ my_func(a) for a in ds.Tair.values.flatten()]]]))                   

